# AI Platform custom containers only work with Python ML frameworks?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I am asking from a cloud architect's perspective. I could not find it spelled out in the documentation: Do AI Platform custom containers only support Python ML frameworks, or are other languages also supported?

Whether it makes sense to not use Python is a different topic ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you can build your binaries/libs into a Docker container images, they can be run on AI Platform.

Comment: You are probably right. However, if you want to use hyperparameter tuning you will need to provide the required metrics somehow. Maybe you can also write a Python wrapper for executing arbitrary commands.

Comment: There is a python lib for metric reporting. Please check out the official doc.

Comment: I know :-) I meant when you do not use Python, you need to provide the metrics yourself